# CreateML Transfer Learning model won't run on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, createml

I've trained an Object Detection model in CreateML using **Transfer Learning**.  When I use the model in my iOS project, the prediction works fine on a physical device running iOS 14.6 as well as on an M1 Mac Mini, but throws the following error on a simulator running iOS 14.5 when I call `.prediction(input: ...)`:

```
Failed to evaluate model 0 in pipeline
```

I am aware that the Transfer Learning models require iOS 14+, but the simulator is running 14.5.

I've tried passing in both a `CGImage` and `CVPixelBuffer` with the same result.

If I train the model in "Full Network" mode it fine.

Are Transfer Learning CoreML Models not supported in iOS simulators?  If not, where is that documented and why is it not supported?

Edit: I've also noticed that the preview feature in CreateML and XCode also breaks with "Unknown Error" on Transfer Learning models too.